# cannot assign must be a user instance django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have created a model for form submission which is working fine, I want to create a new model for the submission of documents based on the respective form using the Form id as **Foreign Key** in the documents model

My documents model is as follow:

```
class PHDDocument(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(HigherStudiesForms, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    admission_letter = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)
    award_letter = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)
    attested_degree = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)
    cv = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)
    travel_agent = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)
    surety_bond = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)
    attested_surety_bond = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)
    guarantee_cnic = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)
    study_leave = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)
    objection_certificate = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)
    hod_form = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)
    rector_form = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.admission_letter)
```

view method respect to the following model is as below:

```
class PHDFileView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'form_id'
    serializer_class = PHDDocumentSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = PHDDocument.objects.all()
        return queryset

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

The serializer method is as follows:

```
class PHDDocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = PHDDocument
    fields = ('id', 'admission_letter', 'award_letter', 'attested_degree', 'cv', 'travel_agent', 'surety_bond',
              'attested_surety_bond', 'guarantee_cnic', 'study_leave', 'objection_certificate', 'hod_form',
              'rector_form')
```

when I am submitting the documents after the form submission through Angular Django is giving the following error **"ValueError: Cannot assign "User: ahssu": "PHDDocument.user" must be a "HigherStudiesForms" instance."**

Comment: In your **`PHDDocument`** model, the field `user` is referenced to **`HigherStudiesForms`** class. But, in your **`perform_create()`** method of **`PHDFileView`** you've assigned a different value, which is not permitted

Answer (score 0):

As error says:

> ValueError: Cannot assign "User: ahssu": "PHDDocument.user" must be a "HigherStudiesForms" instance.

The instance you are trying to assign for user field is not the same as the instance that the user field accepts.

In your model:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(HigherStudiesForms, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
```

user field points to `HigherStudiesForms` while `request.user` will return an instance from `User` model.

You could change the default user model but this is not the case with the error you provided.

Either change the `HigherStudiesForms` in user field to `User` or pass a `HigherStudiesForms` instance in your serializer.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PHDDocument(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

Comment: I explained in the answer. either change the foreignkey for user field to `User` model or change `serializer.save(user=self.request.user)` and pass a `HigherStudiesForms` instance instead of `self.request.user` which is a `User` model instance

Comment: Can you please help me out how will I create "HigherStudiesForms" model instance in place of "self.request.user"

Comment: You can create a new one `HigherStudiesForms.objects.create()` or you can get one with `.get()`. You should read django docs before doing this really.